# How to float/overlap a view in android?

Tags: android, layout

I have many activities with a scrollview inside a tablelayout. However, it is necessary a small design change, so I have to put a black transparent view over the whole screen from the top to the bottom. Is it possible to do it in the tablelayout or the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` allows for easy overlapping of views.  You'll have to adjust the existing views in your app because it doesn't do anything automatically.

EDIT:

A quick way to do this would be to take your existing view (the `ScrollView`) that is already organized and put it in a top-level `RelativeLayout`.  Then, all you have to do is add new view inside the RelativeLayout with the width and height both set to `MATCH_PARENT`.  The result should be the black transparent view will be visible over the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use FrameLayout to achieve any kind of 'layering' of views.

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

  //your existing layout

  <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#33000000" />
</FrameLayout>
```

As DeeV said, you can probably use RelativeLayout in a similar way, but you might have to set additional attributes on its children to achieve this.